# unique lifing property

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, homotopy-theory, covering-spaces

I'm studying Hatcher's book by myslef. I am confused about the proof of Proposition 1.34 on page 62.

Given a covering space $p:\overline X → X $ and a map $f:Y → X$, if two lifts $\overline f_1 ,\overline f_2 :Y → \overline X $ of $f$ agree at one point of $\ Y $and $\ Y$ is connected, then$\overline f_1$ and $\overline f_2$ agree on all of    $ \ Y .$

I understand the ideal of the proof. But the last step is not clear for me. He said that the set of points where $\overline f_1$ and $\overline f_2$ agree is both open and closed in $Y$. The set open is clearly, but why is closed. I am really don't know the reason.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you understand why the set of points they agree on is open. By the same reason, the set of points they *disagree* on is also open. So the complement (i.e., where they agree) is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let us denote
$$\mathscr{A}=\{y\in Y: \tilde{f_1}(y)=\tilde{f_2}(y)\}.$$
Hatcher proved that if $\tilde{f_1}(y)=\tilde{f_1}(y)$, then there is a neighborhood $N$ in $Y$ containing $y$ such that $\tilde{f_1}=\tilde{f_2}$ in $N$. But what is a neighborhood of $y$? It is a set containing a smaller open set $U_y\ni y$. Thus for every $y\in \mathscr{A}$, we have that $U_y\subset \mathscr{A}$. So we have $\mathscr{A}=\bigcup_{y\in \mathscr{A}} U_y$, which is a union of open sets, hence open.

The exact same argument shows that the complement of $\mathscr{A}$ is open, so $\mathscr{A}$ is also closed.